# Cargar JTextFields desde base de datos: solo carga un resultado de lista

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

Estoy intentando que unos `JTextField` se llenen con los nombres guardados en una base de datos con el siguiente código:

```
if(btnGrupo1.isSelected()) {
    try {
        for (int i=0;i<nombres.length;i++) {
            ResultSet rs;
            String sql = "SELECT nombre FROM personas WHERE grupo = 'Grupo1'";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                nombres[i].setText(rs.getString("nombre"));
            }
        }

    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

El problema es que solo se carga un nombre de la lista, cuando quiero que se carguen todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que funcione como quieres esta parte de código debe estar fuera del `for`:

```
ResultSet rs;
String sql = "SELECT nombre FROM personas WHERE grupo = 'Grupo1'";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

¿Cual es la razón? En cada iteración vuelves a obtener los datos de la base de datos, entonces vuelves poner el cursor al principio de los resultados y no permites que `next()` avance

**Edición:**

```
    try {
           ResultSet rs;
           String sql = "SELECT nombre FROM personas WHERE grupo = 'Grupo1'";
           PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
           rs = ps.executeQuery();
            for (int i=0;i<nombres.length;i++) {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    nombres[i].setText(rs.getString("nombre"));
                }
            }

        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: creo que deberias darle la explicacion del error, sin embargo tu respuesta lo soluciona